# On macOS Catalina, what are the default permissions for the /Users folder?

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod, macos-catalina

I have done a very stupid thing and, welp...

```
chmod 755 /Users
```

Tried googling but I just cannot seem to find any info as to what permissions should this folder have. Scared to break the system while trying to fix security issue, so maybe there is the way to automatically fix permissions to, like, some default values?

Before you reply, no, there is no "First aid" section in the Disk Utility, just the "First aid" button, which executes First Aid script on the selected drive.

Comment: 755 is the standard mode for /Users on Catalina so this shouldn't cause trouble.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you! Can you please post it as an answer so that I can pick it as the correct solution?